# How to fetch data using post or get method using an URL

Tags: android, json

I need to get values from [this URL](http://xid.e42.in/testMobile.php) using web services

Comment: @shivaKumarg plz give which parameter pass on this url

Comment: use parameter as getString

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

when i try your url :http://xid.e42.in/testMobile.php

i get this respone : [image]

Comment: i am also getting this one..i don't know whether this is answer or not?

Comment: @shivakumarlg then plz make webservice correct in this webservice you not get data

Comment: @shivakumarlg make like this type webservice : https://www.lnksocial.com/appservice/index.php?lnkdashboard=All&lnkdashboarduserid=5&lnkpostlimit=20&lnkpostpage=2

Comment: which web service you are using?

Comment: @shivakumarlg i am using php webservice

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:-** You can use JSON PARSER class like :-

> add this line in build.gradle file android {  useLibrary
>   'org.apache.http.legacy' }

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
               HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Now, You can use it by METHOD GET or POST like :-

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","1")); //any get or post parameter
        final JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://xid.e42.in/testMobile.php", "GET", params);
```

You will get json object..you can get all your json data through JSONArray..

**Option 2** You can use StringRequest  through **Android Volley** its simple just Google it..

If you have any query comment below :)
Happy Coding